# Error when use remote components with hooks and module federations with nextjs

Tags: next.js, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I receive this error when use hooks in component from remote app when
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BHdc.png)
i use now nextjs13 with module federations

how to resolve this

my component remote app

```
 'use client'
    import { useState } from 'react'
    export default function Button() {
      const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
      return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>adicionar</button>
          <h1>{count}</h1>
        </div>
      )
    }
```

my component in host

```
'use client'
    import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
    import React, { useState } from 'react'
    const RemoteComponent = dynamic({
      loader: async () => {
        const { default: RemoteComponent } = await import('front_login/Button')
        return () => <RemoteComponent />
      },
    })
    export default function Auth() {
      return (
        <>
          <RemoteComponent />
        </>
      )
    }
```

my next-config.js in host

```
const { NextFederationPlugin } = require('@module-federation/nextjs-mf')

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const nextConfig = {
  output: 'standalone',
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },

  webpack: (config, options) => {
    const { isServer } = options

    Object.assign(config.experiments, { topLevelAwait: true })
    config.watchOptions = {
      poll: 1000,
      aggregateTimeout: 300,
    }

    config.plugins.push(
      new NextFederationPlugin({
        name: 'front_gateway',
        remotes: {
          front_login: `front_login@${process.env.FRONT_LOGIN}/_next/static/${
            isServer ? 'ssr' : 'chunks'
          }/remoteEntry.js`,
        },
        filename: 'static/chunks/remoteEntry.js',
        shared: {
          'styled-components': {
            requiredVersion: false,
            eager: true,
            singleton: true,
          },
        },
      }),
    )
    return config
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

my next config in remote app

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const { NextFederationPlugin } = require('@module-federation/nextjs-mf')
const nextConfig = {
  output: 'standalone',

  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    const { isServer } = options

    config.watchOptions = {
      poll: 1000,
      aggregateTimeout: 300,
    }

    config.plugins.push(
      new NextFederationPlugin({
        name: 'front_login',

        remotes: {
          front_gateway: `front_gateway@${
            process.env.FRONT_GATEWAY
          }/_next/static/${isServer ? 'ssr' : 'chunks'}/remoteEntry.js`,
        },
        filename: 'static/chunks/remoteEntry.js',

        exposes: {
          './Button': './src/app/components/Button/button.tsx',
          './Doidao': './src/app/doidao/page.tsx',
        },
        shared: {
          'styled-components': {
            singleton: true,
            eager: true,
            requiredVersion: false,
          },
        },
      }),
    )

    return config
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Please i need help to fix this
When use remote component in remote app, work with success but in host not working

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use suspense with lazy components?

Comment: [Can you transcribe the error you are getting into text format?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  (including the traceback, if relevant.) This helps people with similar questions find your thread and get the help they need in the future.